# Print the contents of a 2D array with row numbers and a word before each printed array value

Tags: java, file, file-io

I am trying to write a 2D Array to a text file but in a way that shows the row number at the beginning of each line as well as having a word before each value that is printed to the file. For example I would like the program to write each element like this ItemNo followed by the value that is contained in the array element. Like below:

```
Row 1: ItemNo3 ItemNo5 ItemNo8
Row 2: ItemNo9 ItemNo10 ItemNo12
Row 3: ItemNo15 ItemNo17 ItemNo18
```

I've been staring at my screen for awhile now and just cant get my head around this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int[][] arr = new int[3][3];

        //fill array
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = j;
            }
        }

        //create path
        Path path = Paths.get("your\\path\\to\\file");

        try {
            //check if file exists; if not, create it
            if(!(new File(path.toString()).exists())) {
                Files.write(path, ("").getBytes());
            }

            int row = 1;
            //iterate through the 2D array
            for(int[] a : arr) {
                //write the row number
                Files.write(path, ("Row" + row + ": ").getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                for(int val : a) {
                    //write the ItemNo
                    Files.write(path, ("ItemNo" + val + " ").getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                }
                row++;
                //write a newline
                Files.write(path, (System.getProperty("line.separator")).getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```